# Cannot play random Cataclysm dungeon

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I'm level 80, so I'm shown the option to play a "random Cataclysm dungeon", but when I try to play, by clicking "Find Group", the following message appears:

> You do not meet the requirements for the chosen dungeons.

But not requirements are listed.

How do I determine what I need to play these dungeons?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To queue for a random dungeon with the LFG tool, you will have to meet the minimum item level requirements for all Cataclysm dungeons in that particular mode. If you queue for a specific dungeon, you simply need to meet the average item level requirement for that dungeon.

The 'average item level' (ilvl) is a computed number that represents the quality of all of your gear.

According to [Wowpedia](http://www.wowpedia.org/Dungeon_Finder):

#### Normal Dungeons

- Blackrock Caverns: 226
- Throne of the Tides: 226
- The Stonecore: 272
- The Vortex Pinnacle: 272
- Grim Batol: 305
- Halls of Origination: 305
- Lost City of the Tol'vir: 305

#### Heroic Dungeons

All pre-zandalari heroics require a minimum item level of 329.

#### Heroic Rise of Zandalari Dungeons

These heroics require a minimum item level of 346.

Answer (score 7):

Change the type from "Random ..." to "Specific Dungeons", then checkout the Cataclysm section, hover the listed dungeons to see why you can play them (they should be locked).

Answer (score 1):

Unless they patched it, in addition to minimum equipment levels, you also need to physically discover the location of the entrance of the instance in order to queue for it.

Comment: They did indeed patch this! As of patch 4.0.6 you no longer need to discover the instance entrance! (too many people were dodging Stonecore this way!)